# Casting Inner Class to a superclass

Tags: java, casting, inner-classes

I'm actually casting subclasses to superclasses through a code line.
Because of special needs, i've made an Inner Class, but i'm not able to cast, at least with the same code, this class into superclass

Example

```
((Indicator)listaIndicatori.elementAt(i)).draw(this,schermo);
```

Works.

```
((Indicator)listaIndicatori.elementAt(i)).draw(this,schermo);
```

Does not work with an Inner Class of Indicator.

The Inner class is declared inside indicator class as follows

```
public class Bars extends JPanel
```

How can i solve?

Comment: is your inner class sub-class of your outer class?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work" and how is your listaIndicatori declared?

Comment: im sorry if i was not accurate. I get this runtime exception Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ClassCastException: Indicator$Bar cannot be cast to Indicator

Answer (score 3):

If the inner class doesn't extend the outer class, the cast won't work:

```
public class Bars extends JPanel
```

`Bars` does not extend `Indicator`.

You can solve this by extending `Indicator`, if `Indicator` itself extends `JPanel` (directly or indirectly, if you want to maintain the `JPanel` inheritance on `Bars`):

```
public class Bars extends Indicator
```

**Update**: But, if you actually need to access the outer class instance from an inner class instance, you can use this method inside of `Bars`:

```
public Indicator getIndicator() {
  return Indicator.this;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
(((Indicator.Bars)listaIndicatori.elementAt(i)).getIndicator()).draw(this,schermo);
```

Thanks to Jan Dvorak in the comments for pointing this out!

Comment: I think there's a syntax like `listaIndicatori.Indicator.this` to access the associated `Indicator`, am I right?

Comment: You'd use `Indicator.this` to access the instance of `Indicator` inside the non-static inner class `Bars`.

Comment: I think that's what the asker actually wants to do

Comment: @JanDvorak: You could be right, it's not a matter of casting then, but of accessing the outer class instance.

Comment: I think its what @JanDvorak thinks (I hadn't read his comment before posting my answer)

Comment: Indicator cant extends JPanel because in some cases it's subclassed doesnt need a JPanel. Please, read my first comment :-) I've added one important information

Comment: OK, then just read the second part of my answer, about exposing the outer instance from the inner class instance.

Comment: i get this error
The method getIndicator() is undefined for the type Object

Comment: @mark: I added a cast to `Bars` before calling `getIndicator()`

Comment: Thank you :-) but the Vector contains different kind of objects (all extends Indicator), so i will not be able to cast

Comment: Then I suggest you make them all implement a common interface that has the `getIndicator()` method.

Comment: It does not solve the problem, because there should be some no- static/final variables that are common for all the actual Indicator's subclasses

Comment: @mark: I meant to create an `Indicator` _accessor_ interface, not an interface for the `Indicator` class. Your interface will simply have the `Indicator getIndicator()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Casting a variable of type A to type B works only if the variable indeed references an object whose concrete type is or extends B.

For example:

```
Object o = "hello";
String s = (String) o;
```

works, because the variable `o` references an object which *is* a String.

But doing

```
Object o = "hello";
Integer i = (Integer) o;
```

won't work because o doesn't reference an Integer.

So obviously, casting an instance of JPanel to Indicator won't work, unless the class actually implements the Indicator interface. Whether the class is an inner class or not doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Indicator {
  ....
  class Bar extends JPanel {
    ....
    void foo() {
      ((Indicator)listaIndicatori.elementAt(i)).draw(Indicator.this,schermo);
    }
  }
}
```

Inside `Bar`, the instance of the outer class is accessed by `Indicator.this`.

Comment: i think i cant use this method, because the listaIndicatori vector contains different objects (but all extends Indicator) so i cannot call this method if i don't know the Object's Class. Probably is there a way to know the class name :-)

Comment: In that case I don't understand the problem. Please post more code and explain your question. In its current form it is not understandable